# caret ^ is converting to some special symbol

Tags: linux, unix, mainframe

I'm transferring the file which has the content like below from mainframe system to a Unix instance. I've a delimiter in the file as `^&*`. I'm sending the same in mainframe but when we receive the file in the unix we're receiving as `Ø&*`.

I'm using connect direct to transfer the file from one system to another.

File Type: Flat File, File transfer: CD (Connect Direct)

file content

```
H^&*20220407^&*160009^&*2006
T^&*1
```

But when I receive the file in the unix server I can the file content is changed. Mainly `^` is converted to `Ø`.

```
HØ&*20220407Ø&*160009Ø&*2006
TØ&*1
```

[image: Mainframe details]

Comment: I advise you to use backticks to show special characters (obviously, when your special character is a backtick then you need to work another way).  
The asterisk is used in this site as a formatting character (one asterisk makes *italic* font, two make **bold** font).

Comment: `transferring` how? Using what protocol? What medium? What format? `the file` what file? What is the content of the file, exactly? Please post a snippet. `from mainframe system` what system exactly? what architecture? What is running on that system? What program is sending the data in what way? `to a open system` what system exactly? What architecture? `is on Unix` What unix verison? Are you running on PDP-7? Is it a linux? If so, what distribution? What program is receiving the data?

Comment: `I'm sending the same` how have you checked it exactly? `when we receive the file` how have you checked it exactly? What tools have you used? What command exactly did you used, if you used any? Please post an [MCVE], specify tools and versions of them that you are using, specify the environment that you are using. You tagged `ebcdic` and `ascii` - how are they related to your question? Please post the `locale` output on both systems, if any. Are the systems compatible with POSIX? What is the `locale` output, if any, on those systems? What C standard library are they using, if any? etc.

Comment: I would really want to see this in hex in case they are really ¬ characters. And the code page of your 3270 emulator as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most surely a code page problem.

The data in the file on the mainframe is (most probably) in some EBCDIC code page. ConnectDirect is doing a code page tranformation when sending the file to that UNIX system. This is what the `XLATE(YES)` means.

However, there is some default code page "from"-"to" pair configured, which is being used with `XLATE(YES)`. But this probably is not the correct pair. You need to

- find out what EBCDIC code page the data on the mainframe is encoded in. Is it IBM-037, IBM-1047, IBM-500, IBM-273, etc. There are many.
- find out what code page the data shall be in on the UNIX side: UTF-8, ISO8859-1, 437, etc. There are many.
- make sure ConnectDirect will transform using the correct source and target code pages.

Ask your ConnectDirect support people to help you with this.